# How do I get a consistent markup font size across models when using the Autodesk Forge Viewer MarkupsCore extension?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the MarkupsCore extension to make persistent text markups on a bunch of different 2D models. I'm setting the style like this:

```
markupsExt.setStyle({"font-size" : .12});
```

Usually this works. But sometimes, depending on the .dwg file that gets uploaded to Forge, the markups are way too small. I have no control over the files that get uploaded and I have no idea how they are configured when they are created in AutoCad.

What's going on here and how can I achieve a consistent font size in my markups no matter what model I'm marking up?

Comment: what's the Viewer version? I'll check on it and try to reproduce. Do you know the UNITS of the DWGs?

Comment: checking on it, got no reply from you

Comment: I'm using version 3.3 of the viewer and the DWGs are in Architectural (feet and inches) units. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: as you said it is eventually failing, my first suggestion would be to migrate to Viewer v6 (latest), we've implemented several improvements and maybe this already addressed. If it persists, would it be possible to share a non-confidential sample file? Please do not send any trade secret information. The email is forge.help[at]autodesk.com

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll migrate to v6 and see what happens. It probably won't be possible to share a sample file though.

Comment: did the suggestion help?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Migrating to v6 seems to have fixed this issue. Apologies for the delay. The upgrade took a while.